# java script to alert the mutile option selected ..in<select> HTMl tag. and tag .is not inside <form>tag body

Tags: javascript

java script to alert the mutile option selected ..in`<select>` HTMl tag. and tag .is not inside  `<form>`tag body how will do it ....

thank you

Comment: ...what? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("sel1").getElementsByTagName("option");
var len = elem.length;
var sel = new Array();

for(i=0; i<len;i++)
{
    if(elem[i].selected == true)
    {
        sel.push(elem[i].value);
    }   
}

alert(sel.join());
```

**[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/uriru3/2)**